# Localize terms in bibtex/biblatex entries

Tags: biblatex, languages

Is there a way I could localize terms in my bibtex entries?

example:

> note = {to appear}

I use a bibtex file for articles in english and german and it would be nice to replace the "to appear" in the bibliography with a localized string.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`biblatex` provides a `pubstate` field for publication states, so I suggest to use this field instead of the `note` field. For localized strings, use the `\bibstring` macro. See section 4.8 of the manual for details about `\bibstring` and section 4.9.2.11 for the publication states defined by default. If you really nead an additional `toappear` state, here's how to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{toappear}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  toappear = {to appear},
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  toappear = {im Erscheinen},
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  pubstate = {\bibstring{toappear}},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  pubstate = {\bibstring{inpress}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that in newer versions of `biblatex` the `\bibstring` in `pubstate` is not needed any more, it will be added automatically if applicable.

Answer (score 6):

I would use the more standard `pubstate={forthcoming}` as an entry field, that is probably already localized in the biblatex style you are using, i.e.:

```
@article{Till2015,
author={Till},
title={The Philosophical Foundations of Alchemy},
journal={Alchemy Review},
pubstate={forthcoming},
date={2015}}
```