# How to enter publications "in press", or "submitted to" in BibTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, sorting

Is there a convention for how to enter publications that are "in preparation" or "submitted to *Some Journal*" into a BibTeX database?

Comment: Usually the `notes` field is used for this.

Comment: With `biblatex`, you may also add the `pubstate` field to the entries of your `.bib` database. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/localize-terms-in-bibtex-biblatex-entries/25091#25091.

Comment: I used biblatex with \citeuathor as described in one of the answers in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38808/truncation-of-year-field-in-author-year-citations-using-apalike-bibliography

Answer (score 87):

One can enter non-numeric information -- such as "in press" and "forthcoming" -- directly in the `year` field of a bibliographic entry.

The only time that having non-numeric information in the `year` field may cause trouble is if you (a) have *several* "in-press" pieces by the same author(s) and (b) need to ensure that the entries are sorted in a certain order. Fortunately, an easy fix for this is suggested in the BibTeX manual:

- First, set up a command named `\noop` (short for "no operation"): At the top of your .bib file, you should enter

  ```
    @preamble{ " \newcommand{\noop}[1]{} " } % a do-nothing command that serves a purpose
  ```
- Later on in the bib file, you'd augment the year fields of the "in-press" entries as follows:

  ```
    @article{smith:2011,
      author  = "John Smith", 
      year    = 2011,
      journal = "Unorganized Scholarly Impressions",
      ... }
    @article{smith:inpress-a,
      author  = "John Smith", 
      year    = "\noop{3001}in press",
      journal = "Journal of Nothingness",
      ... }
    @article{smith:inpress-b,
       author  = "John Smith", 
       year    = "\noop{3002}forthcoming",
       journal = "Review of Random Thoughts",
       ... }
  ```
- With this setup, and assuming you're employing a bibliography style that sorts entries by year, "smith:2011" will always be listed before "smith:inpress-a" which, in turn, will always be listed before "smith:inpress-b".
- Note that `\noop{<anything>}` generates no *LaTeX* output. However, it is still useful, because when *BibTeX* encounters it while building the bibliography file (which will have the file name extension `.bbl`), it will "see" the contents of the two year fields as `3001in press` and `3002forthcoming`, respectively, and thus perform its sorting job correctly.
- Observe that I recommend using fake years -- such as `3001`, `3002`, and so on -- to make clear to all readers of the `.bib` file (including yourself!) that these aren't real publication dates but are being used solely for the purpose of ensuring a correct sorting order.

The `natbib` citation command `\citet{smith:inpress-a,smith:inpress:b}` will generate

> Smith (in press, forthcoming)

This may well be confusing to your readers. To avoid this problem -- and assuming, for the sake of this example, that both pieces will be published later in 2012 -- you'll have to change the two year fields to something such as

```
year = "\noop{3001}in press 2012a"
```

and

```
year = "\noop{3002}in press 2012b"
```

respectively. With these modifications in place, the command `\citet{smith:inpress-a,smith:inpress:b}` will generate the more readily parsable output

> Smith (in press 2012a, in press 2012b)

Later on, once the pieces are published, you can update the `.bib` file and replace "\noop{3001}in press 2012a" with the actual publication year -- which may turn out to be `2013`. (Obviously, you'll want to use that opportunity to also enter the actual values of the entry's other fields, such as `volume`, `issue`, `pages`, etc.)

---

**Addendum**: Note that the `\noop` command can also be used to impose a sorting order on pieces that have already been published. Suppose that you have three entries published in 2005 by the particularly prolific "John Miller", with keys `miller:2005a`, `miller:2005b`, and `miller:2005c`; let's assume the keys were chosen in this manner because you happen to know that the 2005a piece was published in February, the 2005b piece in June, and the 2005c piece in October 2005. Suppose further that all three entries currently contain the field `year = 2005`. If two or three publications are to be included in a bibliography that's sorted by author and year, there's unfortunately no guarantee that BibTeX will list these entries according to the values of their keys. If it matters to you that the `miller:2005a`, `miller:2005b`, and `miller:2005c` entries will always be sorted and thus listed in this order, you could use the `\noop` command and modify the entries' `year` fields as follows:

```
@article{miller:2005a,
   author = "John Miller",
   year   = "2005{\noop{a}}",
   ...
}
@article{miller:2005b,
   author = "John Miller",
   year   = "2005{\noop{b}}",
   ...
}
@article{miller:2005c,
   author = "John Miller",
   year   = "2005{\noop{c}}",
   ...
}
```

That way, if for a given publication you need to include the pieces with keys `2005b` and `2005c`, BibTeX will indeed sort them in the desired order. And, depending on the bib style file in use, BibTeX will use the augmented year labels `2005a` and `2005b` when the `.bbl` file is created.

Comment: Instead of calling the command \noop, would it make sense to call it \sortorder - so that it's clear what's going on? Or would there be some other undesirable consequences from this?

Comment: @jhabbott - Thanks. I can't think of any undesirable consequences of naming the macro `\sortorder`. A personal anecdote: in the close to five years that have passed since I posted this answer, I've actually switched from `\noop` to `\noopsort` in my own work (i.e., my own working papers) -- precisely to provide a clue as to the macro's purpose. I'm pretty sure that `\noopsort` is also the name used in some of the original BibTeX documentation.

Comment: With `pdflatex` I get only the last four characters of the `Year` field in the citation. E.g. a field like `year = "\noop{3001}in press"`, produces a citation like *(de Sousa, ress)*.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa - The way the year field is rendered is governed by the bibliography style. Which bibliography style does your document employ?

Comment: I am using `apalike`.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa - Indeed, `apalike` is a bibliography style that truncates the `year` field. :-( I suggest you proceed as follows: (i) Find the file `apalike.bst` in your TeX distribution, make a copy of this file, and call the copy, say, `myapalike.bst`. (ii) Open the file `myapalike.bst` in a text editor, go to line 909, and delete the string `#-1 #4 substring$`. (iii) Save the file `myapalike.bst` in the directory where your main tex file is located, change the argument of `\bibliographystyle` from `apalike` to `myapalike`, and do a full recompile cycle: latex, bibtex, and latex twice more.

Comment: @Mico: after deleting that line, the citations are transformed into random characters, e.g. *(f)* instead of *(de Sousa, 2016)*. Meanwhile I was able to obtain the full *in press* string using the NatBib package.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa - Just for the record: I did *not* suggest you delete an entire line. Instead, I suggested you delete a certain string -- only about half of that line.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa - How did you do it in natbib?

Comment: How to implement all this when working with JabRef instead? If I fill up the year as said above, it's not working!

Comment: @Ash - No idea, as I don’t use JabRef.

Comment: @Mico suggestion on deleting the `#-1 #4 substring$` string worked for me. But then had to stop using `\noop` as it was algo being displayed as written in the citation.

Comment: @b-fg - Which bibliography style do you employ? `apalike`?

Comment: Yes, `apalike`.

Comment: @b-fg - Not sure what to tell you, except maybe to double-check that the `\noop` directives are themselves encased in curly braces. E.g., `"3001{\noop{a}}"` should work, whereas `"3001\noop{a}"` probably won't.

Comment: Weirdly, not using `\noop` at all works too. Currently have: `year = {2020, accepted},` and it's displayed correctly in the citation and references. Probably something to do with `apalike`.

Comment: @b-fg - There are two separate things going on here. The first is that by modifying `apalike.bst` to remove `#-1 #4 substring$`, you give yourself the opportunity to *display* the citation call-out and the formatted bibliography entry with a `year` field as `2020, accepted`. That's independent of the second thing, which is that by affixing `{\noop{a}}` etc to the (plain or augmented) `year` fields, you can influence the way these entries are *sorted*.

Answer (score 46):

If you are using a traditional BibTeX style file, use the `@unpublished` type and use the `note` field to explain the status. If you are using `biblatex`, then you can use the `@article` type and add the information to the `note`: `biblatex` tends to be more forgiving in what is 'required' for an `article`.

Comment: I could be wrong, but doesn't the `notes` field show up in the output with the `@article` type as well?

Comment: @ReidPriedhorsky It does, but some BibTeX styles issue a warning if you have no year, volume or pages for an `@article` entry. Some may give very odd formatting as a result, so I'd avoid that unless using `biblatex`. In the later case, there are not really any 'required' fields in the same way as traditional BibTeX, so the problem is avoided.

Comment: In my version [BibTeX 0.99c (TeX Live 2009/Debian)], this works if I use the type `@article` and the field name `note`, rather than `notes`.

Comment: I confirm that `note` should be used instead of `notes` also for the `@unpusblished` format (I took the liberty to edit the post since it has not been fixed in 10 years).