# Stop bibtex from complaining about an empty note

Tags: bibtex, natbib, warnings

When I `bibtex foo.tex` the following foo.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
\cite{citation1}
\bibliography{foo}
\end{document}
```

with this entry in `foo.bib`

```
@unpublished{citation1,
author = {bob},
number = {2},
pages = {8--13},
title = {{test title}},
volume = {12},
year = {1492}
}
```

Bibtex complains:

```
Warning--empty note in citation1
```

Can I avoid this warning (in a way that is not much more difficult than ignoring it)?

Comment: For the entry type `@unpublished`, `note` is one of the mandatory fields, so BibTeX is complaining "by design".

Comment: Taking a closer look at your `citation1` entry: Is this a yet-to-be published article where the journal is already known (because you specify year, volume, number and pages)? If so, use `@article` and add a note (here: optional) saying "forthcoming" or " in press".

Comment: @lockstep it is actually a working paper / conference proceedings

Comment: I see. Choose `@conference` or `@inproceedings`, add the optional `note` field, and the warning should vanish.

Comment: @lockstep `@generic` works so I posted this workaround as an answer, and then updated my answer with the other types you mention. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As pointed out by @lockstep in the comments, `note` is one of the mandatory fields for the `@unpublished` entry type.

This warning will disappear if you change the entrytype from `@unpublished` to `@generic`, `@conference`, or `@inproceedings`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing the entry type you can also enter an actual note in the `Extra` field. For example, for the `@Manuscript` entry I usually enter 'working paper' or 'unpublished.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trick Tex into thinking you've filled in the `note` field. At the top of your .bib file define the following `\noop` command from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31384/how-to-enter-publications-in-press-or-submitted-to-in-bibtex):

```
@preamble{ " \newcommand{\noop}[1]{} " } % a do-nothing command that serves a purpose
```

Then in your .bib:

```
@unpublished{citation1,
author = {bob},
number = {2},
pages = {8--13},
title = {{test title}},
volume = {12},
year = {1492},
note = {\noop{}}
}
```