# Bib entry with urldate but no year uses the year of urldate as year

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

Hi i have the following bibliographic entry:

```
@misc{Wikipedia,
author = {Wikipedia},
title = {{Software performance testing}},
url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software\_performance\_testing\#Load\_testing},
urldate = {2013-07-10}
}
```

This entry gets rendered like the following in the bibliography:
[image]

if i add a `year` tag of 2012 to the entry, it becomes:
[image]

I think this is wrong, shouldn't i say something like (o.D. is a german abbreviation for no date, "Besucht am" is "visited at")

> Wikipedia o.D. Software Performance testing. Besucht am 10.Juli 2013

? How can i achieve this?

Comment: Would the informaton in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31384/5001 help? There's nothing stopping you from providing a `year` field with a value of `(o.D.)`.