# Biblatex inherits publication date from urldate in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

Using biber, I do not encounter this issue but I want to use bibtex for the backend option.

I have an "online" bibitem with an accessed on date but no publication date.
I want the output to be along the lines of AUTHOR (n.d.) URL [Accessed on: dd/mm/year].

I can only find a way to do this by clearing the urlyear, which I don't want to do. Furthermore, [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129411/bib-entry-with-urldate-but-no-year-uses-the-year-of-urldate-as-year) suggests setting the year to the text "n.d." however this generates a warning about issues with sorting which I would like to avoid.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, urldate=long, dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  date = {},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  url     = {https://example.com/gov/sir-humphrey/importance-civil-service},
  urldate = {2018-08-23},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to display n.d. or similar in the empty brackets.
I could do this either by:

- Preventing the publication date being inherited from the access date.
- Manually setting the date to be "null" somehow, but doing this it gives ("null") as the date in the ways that I have tried.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use `bibtex` as your backend, then you can specify `year = {nodate}` instead of using the `date` field.

**Aside:** If you use `biber` as backend, then I think the easiest option is just to alter the definition of `\DeclareLabeldate` to remove `urldate` from the list of allowable fields. e.g.,

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \literal{nodate}
}
```

## MWE using `bibtex` as backend

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=bibtex, urldate=long, dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@online{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  year    = {nodate},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  url     = {https://example.com/gov/sir-humphrey/importance-civil-service},
  urldate = {2018-08-23},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]