# Multiple In preparation citations by same authors

Tags: bibtex, natbib, multiple-citations

I am attempting to cite previous chapters in my dissertation using bibtex, but most of these are currently unpublished so I am citing them as in prepartion. I have attempted to use the \noop{} functionality but have encountered an issue. When I attempt to cite the previous 3 chapters in the fourth chapter the last in preparation chapter is cited as "I" . For example, when I compile the command `\citep{Vincent17, Chapter2, Chapter3}` ,  I get the following

> (Vincent et al. 2017; In Preparation 2017a;I).

If I cite only Chapter3 I get the result I expect of (Vincent et al. In Preparation 2017b). I started out the In Preparation without the "a" and "b", but Bibtex was not adding them. Below are the relevant citations. I am using the natbib and hyperref and cleveref packages.

```
@Article{Vincent17,
  author =   {Matthew T Vincent and Travis O Brenden and James R Bence},
  title =    {Simulation testing the robustness of a multi-region tag-integrated assessment model that exhibits natal homing and estimates natural mortality and reporting rate},
  journal =      {Can. J. Fish. Aquat. Sci.},
  year =     {2017}
}

@Article{Chapter2,
  author =   {Matthew T Vincent and Travis O Brenden and James R Bence},
  title =    {Parameter estimation performance in a recovery-conditioned integrated tagging catch-at-age analysis model},
  journal =      {Manuscript in Preparation},
  year =     {\noop{3333}In~Preparation 2017a}}
}

@Article{Chapter3,
  author =   {Matthew T Vincent and Travis O Brenden and James R Bence},
  title =    {Testing common assumptions used in simulations of multi-region Integrated Tagging and Catch-at-Age Analysis model performance},
  journal =      {Manuscript in Preparation},
  year =     {\noop{4444}In~Preparation 2017b}}
}
```

Comment: The body of your question talks about `bibtex`, but your question is tagged `biblatex`. Please clarify which one you are using.

Comment: I am using bibtex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I don't think it's proper to use the `@article` entry type for the  entries `Chapter2` and `Chapter3`. You should be using either the `@misc` or the `@unpublished` entry type for these two entries.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: I am using the cjfas.bst, which I obtained from here: https://github.com/seananderson/bst/blob/master/cjfas.bst

Comment: I have attempted to use both the `@misc` and `@unpublished` entry types for the last two entries. When I included In Preparation 2017 as year for both entry types the result was the same.

Comment: @Mico  I was using the `@article` based on the first answer to your question a while ago
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31384/how-to-enter-publications-in-press-or-submitted-to-in-bibtex

Comment: Yeah, those examples were meant to be (parodies of) real journal names. For a piece of information such as "Manuscript in Preparation", I suggest you stick it in a `note` field and that you change the entry type from `@article` to `@misc`.