# Can't correctly cite a forthcoming paper with chicago style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, chicago-style

I want to cite a forthcoming paper and I'm following the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31384/how-to-enter-publications-in-press-or-submitted-to-in-bibtex). My bib file looks like:

```
@preamble{"\newcommand{\noop}[1]{}"}

@Article{somearticle,
  title={{Title}},
  author="A, B and C, D and E, F",
  journal="Journal",
  pubstate = {forthcoming},
  year="{\noop{2001} forthcoming}"
}
```

But when I cite this article in my overleaf document with the code,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}


\begin{document}
\citet{somearticle}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{ref.bib}


\end{document}
```

the output looks like

> A et al. (ming)

It is annoying as the "forthcoming" becomes "ming". When I change the citation style back to "plainnat", everything becomes normal

> A et al. ( forthcoming )

I need the chicago style, any suggestions on how to deal with the small bug?

Comment: Did you try adding additional braces around the word `forthcoming`? Like this: `pubstate = {{forthcoming}},`

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it didn't work.

Comment: The `chicago` bib style is programmed to accept only the four final characters in the `year` field. Not sure why.